# How to properly display a Material UI Native select and change the selection using a state hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Code SandBox Here
https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-brook-jpeio?file=/src/App.js

I acquire an array of values using useEffect hook. The array variable is set using useState hook

The value and onChange attributes of Native Select also uses another state variable and its set function to update it.

Using the below part of code to use the set function to set the selected value of the Native Select just after the useEffect gets the data.

```
 // set the default selection on first load
  if (!isEmpty(combolist)) {
    console.log(combolist[0].name);
    setSelection(combolist[0].name);
  }
```

But this is giving too many renders error.

How to fix this and achieve my objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is move the set the `combolist` in `useEffect` to prevent the multiple re-render.


This is the [solution link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-roentgen-q64j7?file=/src/App.js:730-747).

Comment: Why isnt the combo box not displaying the  new selection value  when a selection is made?

Comment: Since it use `parseInt` transfer `event.target.value` to number. However, it is not appropriate. I change the code a little bit and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a `useEffect` hook for that like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length) {
      const combolist = data.map((obj) => pick(obj, ["id", "name"]));

      // set the default selection on first load
      if (!isEmpty(combolist)) {
        console.log(combolist[0].name);
        setSelection(combolist[0].name);
      }
    }
  }, [data]);
```